# How to increase the character size for CPIME chinese font (Windows 10 Pro)?

Tags: windows, fonts, chinese

Does anyone know how to increase the size of characters that show up when using the font, "Chinese (Traditional Hong Kong SAR) Cantonese Phonetic IME (CPIME)"? I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

I've tried accessing the options tab for this font, but there is no options tab. I'm unsure of how else to solve this problem.

The font is far too small for my eyes. Thank you!

Comment: In which utility you need a larger font: Windows, Word, etc.?

Comment: Word, Windows, Firefox, Edge, etc. everywhere I type CPIME, the area that pops up to select characters is too small. 

Additionally, I just realized that I can't get CPIME to work at all on the command line which is strange. Nothing shows up on Google for this particular issue either.

Comment: If the contents on the screen are too small for you, reduce its resolution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your meaning. You mean reduce the resolution of my monitor to fix this particular issue? I don't see the correlation. I only experience this issue when I try to use CPIME. Bopomofo, Pinyin, Changjie, etc. all work fine. In fact, previously I had a similar problem with Bopomofo, but I fixed that issue in the Options area of the font, and now the character selection popup area is big and much more easy to read.

Comment: Go to Windows *Settings > Time & Language > Language* and click your font. If you have an "Options" button, click it. Search for an option to set it to Large font (may be called "Candidate list").

Comment: As indicated in the OP, there is no Options button for CPIME. The fonts that are included together with this font in the Hong Kong font set, such as Bopomofo and Changjie, both have Option buttons, but CPIME, unfortunately, does not.

Comment: If there is no system-wide option, you may need to solve it inside each application.

Comment: How would that work, for instance, if I wanted to start with CLI? Firefox would be next, but I'd like to try CLI first. "CPIME cli" in Google yields almost no relevant hits.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sogou input; it is my regular input, if you can read basic Chinese. I came here with the same question, I'm giving Win10 a shot but I have multiple issues... my biggest, on Win10 IME the dat file is not editable to batch-add my autocomplete, short sentences... Another : IME has to type a line outside the application I'm typing in (Aegisub)... all these and many more are solved in Sogou.

Comment: But isn't 搜狗 input intended for Pinyin, thus simplified Chinese? CPIME is specifically for Hong Kong Cantonese, so I don't think 搜狗 will work.